# Adding things inside while loop causes syntax error

Tags: ruby, while-loop, syntax-error

I'm trying to read and process lines from a file in Ruby.

I have a while loop that reads each line. If the all the while loop does is split the lines, it works fine. When I add a regex matching clause, I get a syntax error, unexpected kEND
 and syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND

Specifically, here is the code which "compiles"

```
def validate
  invalid = 0
  f = File.open(ARGV[0], "r")
  while (line = f.gets)
    vals = line.split(",")
  end
end

if (ARGV[1] == "validate")
  validate
end
```

while this code

```
def validate
  invalid = 0
  f = File.open(ARGV[0], "r")
  while (line = f.gets)
    vals = line.split(",")

    match0 = Regexp.new(/0-9]{1,4}/)
    unless (match0.match(vals[0]))
      invalid ++
    end
  end
end

if (ARGV[1] == "validate")
  validate
end
```

throws the error

> schedule.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected kEND 
>   schedule.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is not due to the regex. It's due to the "++". Ruby doesn't have the "++" operator. Instead, you should use:

```
invalid += 1
```

Comment: thanks! it's pretty confusing, the kEND error made me think that there's a problem with mismatched 'end's

Answer (score 1):

Besides, there is a bracket missing in your regexp (character class).

```
/0-9]{1,4}/
```

It should read

```
/[0-9]{1,4}/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no C-style increment/decrement operator.  Instead use

```
invalid = invalid + 1
```

or

```
invalid += 1
```